# Yongnuo YN685 (Nikon) and YN622N-TX not triggering

Tags: flash, yongnuo, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash

I just received a YN685 (Nikon) and a YN622N-TX (For Nikon), serial numbers 69020032 and 02072849.
The firmwares are 1.08 (YN622) and 1.3.4 (YN685).

However I try I cannot seem to get wireless communication working between the two.

I am testing this:
Both units stand-alone (YN622) not connected to camera.

Flash set to "622 R Slave" mode, Channel 1, Group C. Zoom set to Auto. The slave indicator of the flash (two red LEDs in the front) is blinking.
On the transmitter, Group C, channel 1 selected. Group C set to TTL.

Now I believe that the flash should zoom according to the setting on the transmitter (622), which does not happen. When I press the "Test" button of the transmitter nothing happens.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have zoom set to Auto. That means that the camera sends the len's focal length to the flash and it zooms accordingly. Since you're testing the triggers without a camera attached, no such information is being sent, which may be why it's not zooming.

I'd recommend testing with a camera/lens attached, or testing with zoom set to manual, so you can actively change the zoom setting from the 622-TX. Likewise, you may also want to test remote power control by setting the flash to manual and adjusting power levels.

Answer (score 0):

The [YN685](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012CX6Y0M) is the Canon version. The Nikon version, which was released several months later, is the [YN685 N](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EFUHRPQ). Are you sure you have a Nikon flash? The Canon version has silver lettering, the Nikon version should have gold lettering.